# How to write multiple csv rows at once?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
Name  Shares  Platform
John  100     Facebook
David 200     Facebook 
Allen 300     Twitter
Maria 10      Instagram
```

I want to create a new file in which I will have the amount of rows for each name and platform based on the shares number.
For instance, for John I'll have 100 rows that include John and Facebook.

How can I do that with Python?

Comment: Did you google `python write csv` - I guess that could be considered "research". And would lead you to module csv, pandas and others which you then could try out and formulate a more specific question. Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need repeat rows by values of column `Shares`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Shares']), ['Name','Platform']].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Name   Platform
0     John   Facebook
1     John   Facebook
2     John   Facebook
3     John   Facebook
4     John   Facebook
..     ...        ...
605  Maria  Instagram
606  Maria  Instagram
607  Maria  Instagram
608  Maria  Instagram
609  Maria  Instagram

[610 rows x 2 columns]

df.to_csv(file1, index=False)
```

Comment: Not a very specific question, neither researched. Answer warranted?